# Load FXML file on tableview row selection

Tags: sql, javafx, tableview, javafx-8, fxml

Please, I would like to load an FXML file on clicking on a tableview row (row selection) and retrieve the values of the row from a database and setting the values on the labels of the FXML file.

The examples I've seen so far doesn't implement thus.

I would appreciate if anybody can help on FXML file loading.

**My current code:**

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Main extends Application {
ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
Parent root =         FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("personsTable.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    newStage.setScene(newScene);
    newStage.show();
try {
         Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employee","Conduct","ccb");

        String rest="select *from Employee";
        pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(rest);
        rs=pstmt.executeQuery();



        while(rs.next()){
            persons.add(new Person(
                    rs.getString("name"),


            ));

            staff.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

            personsTable.setItems(persons);
            personsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Person> observable, Person oldValue, Person newValue) {

            // Create a new FXML loader 
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("OnSelection.fxml"));
            try {
                // Load the another FXML file 
                Parent newParent = loader.load();
                OnSelectionController subController = loader.getController();
                // Set the String property
                // If you want to use data from the current selection: newValue contains the currently selected Person
                // TODO: Get value from DB
                subController.textToDisplay.set(newValue.getName());

                // newParent contains the root of your other FXML file, do anything that you want to do with it (e.g. add to the current node graph)
                // Now I just simply open it in a new window
                Stage newStage = new Stage();
                Scene newScene = new Scene(newParent);
                newStage.setScene(newScene);
                newStage.show();

                } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            });
}

         } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a listener for the [selectedItemProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) of the [selectionModelProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#selectionModelProperty) of your `TableView` in which you can lod your another FXML file using [FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html). You can expose some public methods and/or properties on the controller of this FXML file and you can use this methods and/or properties to set the data in the controller returned by [getController](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--) method of the `FXMLLoader`.

**Minimalistic example with your specification:**

In the example the `TableView` displays `Person` objects, on selection of the `TableView` a second FXML file is loaded and displayed on a new `Stage`.

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 400, Color.WHITE);
        TableView<Person> personsTable = new TableView<Person>();

        // Add only one Column: Name
        TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        personsTable.getColumns().add(nameCol);

        // On selected item
        personsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Person>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Person> observable, Person oldValue, Person newValue) {

                // Create a new FXML loader 
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("OnSelection.fxml"));
                try {
                    // Load the another FXML file 
                    Parent newParent = loader.load();
                    OnSelectionController subController = loader.getController();
                    // Set the String property
                    // If you want to use data from the current selection: newValue contains the currently selected Person
                    // TODO: Get value from DB
                    subController.textToDisplay.set("value from DB for Person" + newValue.getName());

                    // newParent contains the root of your other FXML file, do anything that you want to do with it (e.g. add to the current node graph)
                    // Now I just simply open it in a new window
                    Stage newStage = new Stage();
                    Scene newScene = new Scene(newParent);
                    newStage.setScene(newScene);
                    newStage.show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Create some dummy data for the table
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName("Name" + i);
            person.setAddress("Address" + i);
            person.setCountry("Country" + i);
            person.setCourse("Course" + i);
            persons.add(person);

        }
        personsTable.setItems(persons);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Person.java*

```
public class Person {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String country;
    private String course;

}
```

*OnSelectionController.java*

```
public class OnSelectionController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private Label label1;

    public SimpleStringProperty textToDisplay = new SimpleStringProperty("");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // The text that the label displays is bound to the string property value
        label1.textProperty().bind(textToDisplay);

    }

}
```

*OnSelection.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="191.0" prefWidth="210.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.OnSelectionController">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
  <children>
    <Label fx:id="label1" layoutX="59.0" layoutY="40.0" text="Label" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Please see the comments in the code snippets.

Comment: Thank you . It worked fine but loads more than one window  on row selection. How can I fix that.

Comment: If you are doing the same as in the code, it shall load one window. So to tell what's wrong on your side you could post your current code in the question.

Comment: Do you mean, that if you select one row, it opens a window, then you select another one and it opens one more. Is it the problem?

Comment: I mean if I select one row it opens the number of windows equivalent to the number of rows that are populated in my tableview. For example if I have 10 rows populated on the tableview and I select a row it opens 10 windows.

Comment: The problem is that you add the listener 10 times, becase it is in your while loop.
The only command what shall in the loop is:
persons.add(new Person(rs.getString("name");

Comment: Please, what code do I use then to add the listener only once.

Comment: I added a comment in the code of your question. If you close the while loop there, everything will be fine. The code snippet is not complete, so I cannot remove the current ending "}", so please remove it and add it where my comment is.